# Create a record for many-to-many in DRF

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, django-rest-framework

I'm a new in Django and Im trying to understand work with Django Rest Framework. What I dont get and I've been trying to find out is how to create a new record in DB which has many-to-many relationship. I can read it and retrieve it in JSON but I can't create or modify it. Django created for me a table for indexes but I have no idea how to work with that. 
Exmaple: 
I have a users and user tags. Each user can have more tags and each tag can be assigned to more users.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    category_tags = models.ManyToManyField(CategoryTag, blank=True, null=True)
```

What kind of serializer and how actually should I write a serializer so Ican assign some tags to a user. For example when a new user is registered, during registration he will choose some tags which will be assigned to him. 
I can create a new user but I can't work with m2m (write).

Many thanks.

Comment: Please add your serializer

Comment: Here is my UserSerializer http://pastebin.com/FC6g3v03
As far as i understood, i dont touch the intermediate table which is created  bu Django, but then i dont undestand how to write a new record there (indexes).

Comment: Do you want to create new categories or just add a relation to existing ones?

Comment: i have table of categories and table of users and what I need it is to assign some categories to users (one or more categories to each user). Something like assigning tags to items or blog posts.

Comment: Sorry I was OoO. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you post a list of category id in your JSON. Then you can adjust your `create` method to this:

```
 def create(self, validated_data):
    generated_password = get_random_string(length=8)

    user = User.objects.create(
        email = validated_data['email'],
        full_name = validated_data['full_name']
    )

    user.set_password(generated_password)
    user.save()

    # loop over Categories and add many to many relationship
    for cat_id in validated_data('category_tags'):
        category = Category.objects.get(id=cat_id)
        user.category_tags.add(category)
    user.save()

    return user
```

Your JSON should look similar to this:

```
{
    "email": "some@mail.de",
    ... //other user fields
    "category_tags": [3, 12, 16]
}
```

Comment: Im trying this solution but somehow its not saving it... it does save a new user but it will save it without any tags... I guess its because i have not defined category_tags as a field on the top of the serializer, but i dont know what type it should be...

Comment: Probably `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`. Have a look here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield

Comment: Ive tried it before... when i use `serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=UserTag.objects.all())` ill get the error: `<django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x318a8d0> is not JSON serializable` and when I use `serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)` it wont do anything.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://adiyatmubarak.wordpress.com/tag/django-rest-framework-many-to-many-field/ If you can't get it work, please create a new question.

Comment: I think ive red this article but its about read-only... ill try to post a new question with the whole snippet

Comment: just fyi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36016055/drf-not-creating-m2m-records and thank for your all your help, i really appreciate it.